# Characterize all functions $f$ such that $f(g(x))=f(x)$ if and only if $g(x)=x$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory

While working on a seemingly-unrelated research question, I've stumbled upon the condition I mentioned in the title.

> Is there a name for the class of functions $f$ such that $f(g(x))=f(x)\Longleftrightarrow g(x)=x$?

If $f$ is injective, then $f$ has a left inverse and the result is trivial. So my class has to contain all injective functions. This lets me rephrase my question as:

> Do any non-injective functions $f$ satisfy the condition that $f(g(x))=f(x)\Longleftrightarrow g(x)=x$?

I realize this isn't a very precise question because I don't mention domains, codomains, etc. I don't *really* about what the domains of $f$ and $g$ are...it's more of a general knowledge-type question.

Any sorts of tips, references, etc. would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, $g(x)=x$ implies $f(g(x))=f(x)$ trivially, so the only direction of interest is the other direction: when does $f(g(x))=f(x)$ imply $g(x)=x?$

Comment: Suppose $f$ wasn't injective.  Then there is an $x_1$ and an $x_2$ such that $x_1\neq x_2$ and $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$.  Let $g$ be a function such that $g(x_1)=x_2$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the domain of $f$ by $D$.

If $f$ is noninjective there are points $a\not= b$ in D with $f(a) = f(b)$.  Define a function $g : D \to D$ by $$g(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} b & {\rm if} & x=a \\ x & {\rm if} &x \not= a. \end{array} \right.$$
Then $f(g(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x$, but this does not imply $g(x) = x$.

Your class of functions is precisely the class of injective functions.

Comment: Nice! I wonder if there's an equally clear counterexample if we introduce continuity restrictions...

Comment: there are take for instance $g(x)=x+2\pi$ and $f(x)=\sin(x)$ or $g(x)=-x$ and $f(x)=x^2$. Counterexamples are easy to find.

Comment: I am ashamed that I didn't think of this! Thank you so much for taking the time to share your insight.